# CSS matching predecessor

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have a simple structure:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

If `#b` has class `.test`, I want to set `#a { display: none; }`. Are there any css tricks to acomplish this? We can assume that they are the only childs of their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to select the previous sibling with pure CSS.

If you are up to using the flexbox layout, you could re-arrange the visual order of your two elements, then use the adjacent sibling selector to select the item that is visually first.

For example:

```
<style>
  #a { order: 0; }
  #b { order: -1; }
  #a + #b { color: red; }
</style>
<div style='display: flex; flex-direction: column;'>
  <div id='a'>Hi</div>
  <div id='b'>Bye</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ag266f52/1/

Comment: Actually there are situations where it can be simulated by reversing order using floats or altering text direction.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies long day and didnt read correctly.

If there are only 2 items in the parent you can use :not()

e.g.

html

```
<div class="blue">
  <div id="a">hi</div>
  <div id="b" class="test">his</div>
</div
```

css

```
.blue > :not(.test) {
    color: red;    
 }
```

Comment: That would only work of .test was #a's next sibling, not previous sibling.

Comment: @jack apologies, read wrong. Better solution applied.